# Browsing all SVN repositories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are moving from Visual Sourcesafe to Subversion within our organisation.
I am running SVN via HTTP & Apache.

We will be using a separate repository for each project.

I am using TortoiseSVN and I would have thought by repo browsing to htp://server:12345/svn i would be able to see all the separate repositories.

I get the following error:
“Repository moved permanently to htp://server:12345/svn/; please relocate”

I can browse to each of my repositories past the svn root so
htp://server:12345/svn/Project1 etc

My question is should I be able to do view all the repositories using Tortoise and if so what have I done wrong.

If not then what tools do people use for browsing all there repositories?

I have ViewVC installed and working but I was wondering if I could od this with any client desktop applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, TSVN actually expects that at an URL you give to it there will actually be a valid SVN repository to connect to - either via `file`, `http`, `svn` or some other protocol. SVN (and TSVN for that matter) does not have a notion of "collection of repositories" or "directory of repositories".

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I thought this was the case.  Any suggestions for desktop/web apps for browsing the collection of repositories?
The only one I have seen so far is ViewVC and WebSVN(not so good as you have to add the repos to the config)